# Get previous item in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

I have three records. In order to update every record I need to take previous record's value. Problem is when method is async record three starts to update before record two finish and gets value of null. How can I handle this?

```
const resolvePersons = async (persons) => {
      return Promise.all(persons.map(async (person) => {
        const data = await getSomePersonData(person);
        const value = await getValue(persons); // first person value is statically set
        return { data, value };
      }));
};

function getSomePersonData(person) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve({data: someData}), 100);
}

function getValue(persons) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(persons[index - 1].value), 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Promise.all` and `map` if you don't want the iterations to run concurrently. Just write a normal loop that `await`s something:

```
async function resolvePersons(persons) {
    const result = [];
    for (const [i, person] of persons.entries()) {
        const data = await getSomePersonData(person);
        const prevValue = i == 0 ? null : result[i-1].value;
        const value = await getValue(prevValue);
        result.push({ data, value });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How to use await outside of async function?

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to?

Comment: You use await in non async method

Comment: @TeodorKolev `resolvePersons` is declared as an `async function`, and the `await` in a loop is exactly what you want for sequential processing. What makes you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: @TeodorKolev That rule is causing so much confusion, they'd rather drop it. Too many people take it much too serious, instead of a friendly linter hint. It does not apply in your situation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop#when-not-to-use-it.